# trying to call a value from a class

Tags: flutter, dart

good day everyone 
i am trying to call the avatar value from a class in another file in flutter project as below
first i have a dart file that do authentication with firestore then the data is saved in clas as below
'''

```
UserData currentUser; //defined at the top of the file
Future signInUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult signInUserResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser signInResult = signInUserResult.user;
      DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(signInResult.uid).get();
      currentUser = UserData.fromDocument(doc);
      print(currentUser.email);
      return _userFromFireBase(signInResult);
    } catch (e) {
      print('this is $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

'''

the class called UserData
'''

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserData {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String age;
  final String avatar;
  final String email;
  final String nickname;
  UserData(
      {this.uid, this.name, this.age, this.email, this.nickname, this.avatar});

  factory UserData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return UserData(
      uid: doc['id'],
      name: doc['name'],
      age: doc['age'],
      avatar: doc['avatar'],
      email: doc['email'],
      nickname: doc['nickname'],
    );
  }
}
```

'''
from the authentication file i can print all values of the class UserData like(name, avatar, email...)
but when i try to call it from my Navigation file it give me the below error

```
The getter 'avatar' was called on null.
```

the navigation file as below
'''

```
class NavigationBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'navigation_widget';
  @override
  _NavigationBarWidgetState createState() => _NavigationBarWidgetState();
}

class _NavigationBarWidgetState extends State<NavigationBarWidget> {
  int _screensIndex = 0;
  int index = 2;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    HomePage(),
    PlannerPage(),
    AddPostsPage(currentUser: currentUser,),
    ActivityPage(),
    UserProfile()
  ];

  pageController(index) {
    setState(() {
      //print(currentUser);
      _screensIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    pageController(index);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController(index)?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print(currentUser.email);
    return Scaffold(
      body: _screens[_screensIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        index: 2,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        animationCurve: Curves.easeIn,
        height: 75.0,
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(CupertinoIcons.home, size: 30),
          Icon(CupertinoIcons.location, size: 30),
          Icon(CupertinoIcons.add_circled, size: 35),
          Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart, size: 30),
          Icon(CupertinoIcons.person, size: 30),
        ],
        onTap: pageController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see "avatar" or "UserData" in the code you give

Comment: the class name is UserData and one of the variables is avatar

Comment: I mean I don't see it in the navigation file

Comment: i recall the class by using currentuser '''import 'package:trip_planner/providers/auth_provider.dart';''' currentuser is defined in this file auth_provider.dart

Comment: anyone have answer ?

Comment: what's wrong!!!!!

Comment: actually anyone here?